# Using python script to run commands on msfconsole

Tags: python, os.system, metasploit

Even though it is older, in python you can use `os.system()` to run commands in the terminal.

My question is, if you enter metasploit using `msfconsole`, do the proceeding `os.system()` calls enter the commands into the msfconsole?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
msfconsole -q -x " use exploit/multi/handler; set rhost $targetip;
set lport $lport ; explot ;
```

in `os.system`.